# Interpolating a list

Tags: list-manipulation, interpolation

Here is a sample list

```
data = {{1, 2.1, 55.2}, {2, 2.7, 60}, {3, 3.1, 65}, {4, 3.5, 67}, {5, 4.5, 72}, {6, 4.2, 77}, {7, 5.9, 80}}
```

which contains three rows.

Now, let's create another list

```
ti = 2.;
tf = 6.;
nmax = 200;
dt = (tf - ti)/(nmax - 1);
times = Table[i, {i, ti, tf, dt}];
```

So, we created a list containing 200 equally spaced numbers in the interval [2,6]. These numbers correspond to the second row of the initial `data` list.

Now, I want to interpolate the initial `data` list so as to be able to predict what would be the values of the first and third columns using the 200 list as a second row. So we should obtain a new list `data2` containing as a second row the 200 equally spaced data from `times` list and as first and third columns the interpolated ones. Finally, if possible, I would like to merge `data` and `data2` with ordered columns.

Any ideas?

Comment: `Interpolation[data[[;; , {2, 1}]]]` ?

Comment: @Alx And then, what about `data2`?

Comment: I don't understand why you need `data2`? With this simple interpolation you can sample 1st or 3rd column with any step of the 2nd column.

Comment: @Alx This is not what I want. I want to use the 200 values of `times` and create a new list `data2` containing as a second column the 200 values and as first and third columns the interpolated ones from `data`. Please if possible provide a detailed answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With simple interpolation based on 2nd column:

```
ti = 2.;
tf = 6.;
nmax = 200;
dt = (tf - ti)/(nmax - 1);
int1 = Interpolation[data[[;; , {2, 1}]]] /@ Range[ti, tf, dt] // Quiet;
int2 = Interpolation[data[[;; , {2, 2}]]] /@ Range[ti, tf, dt] // Quiet;
int3 = Interpolation[data[[;; , {2, 3}]]] /@ Range[ti, tf, dt] // Quiet;

newdata = Transpose[{int1, int2, int3}]
```

Comment: This can be done more simply: `newdata = Interpolation[{#2, {##}} & @@@ data] /@ Range[ti, tf, dt] // Quiet`

Answer (score 4):

1. Re-arrange `data` into two lists of `{time, value}` pairs `rdata = data[[All, {2, #}]] & /@ {1, 3}`.
2. Use
   [`TemporalData`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemporalData.html)
   with the option
   [`ResamplingMethod`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ResamplingMethod.html)
   on  `rdata` to get a temporal data object `td`.
3. Use `td["PathFunctions"]` to get the two interpolating functions.
4. Map the interpolating functions to your `times`.

```
td = TemporalData[data[[All, {2, #}]] & /@ {1, 3}, 
   ResamplingMethod -> {"Interpolation", InterpolationOrder -> 1}];

Show[ListPlot[td, PlotMarkers -> Automatic],
 ListPlot[Quiet@Through[td["PathFunctions"]@times], 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}, BaseStyle -> PointSize[Small], 
  Joined -> False, DataRange -> {2, 6}], ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

To get `data2` use

```
data2 = Quiet @
 Transpose[{td["PathFunctions"][[1]] @ #, #, td["PathFunctions"][[2]] @ #}]& @ times
```